# How to get images searched from an input with an url API, using javascript and show to an html page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, api

I have created an input and a button in one html page. From that input I want to "take" the text and use to an url API to search for gifs. After that, I want to copy all src images to my html page to show there the gifs.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Load gif and images</title>
    <!--CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Search for gifs</h1>
    </header>
    <!--Section with input for search-->
    <section id="for-search">
        <form action="javascript: main.js;" onsubmit="return searchgif()">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="type your text here" class="search" id="search">
            <button class="submit">SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
    </section>
    <!--END search section-->
    <!--Section to display gifs for searched word-->
    <section id="layout">
        <div id="result">
            <img id="gif"></img>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--END display section-->
    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//Main JS to search and display GIFS 
function serchgif() {
    var url = "https://b682nc9ec1.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/giphy/search?search=";
    var searched = document.getElementById("search").value;
    var api = url+searched;
    var firstres = api.replace(/[|]|"/g, "");
    var res = firstres.split(",");
    var image = document.getElementById("gif")
    var imgatt = document.createAttribute("src");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <= res.length; i++) {
        imgatt.value = res[i];
        image.setAttributeNode(imgatt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to modify several things in your code (small errors too). But I managed to achieve what you want to do with **fetch**.

```js
buttonEL = document.getElementById("button");
resultEL = document.getElementById("result");

buttonEL.addEventListener("click", searchgif);

function searchgif() {
var url = "https://b682nc9ec1.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/giphy/search?search=";
var searched = document.getElementById("search").value;
var api = url + searched;
var firstres = api.replace(/[|]|"/g, "");
var res = firstres.split(",");

fetch(res, {method: 'GET',  headers: {Accept: 'application/json'} })
.then(function(response) {
        response.json()
 .then(function(text) {
     for ( let i = 0; i <= text.length - 1 ; i++) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("src", text[i]);
  resultEL.appendChild(img);
     }
 });
});
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">

 <title>Load gif and images</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
 <header>
            <h1>Search for gifs</h1>
 </header>
 <!--Section with input for search-->
 <section id="for-search">
            <form>
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="type your text here" class="search" id="search">
            </form>
            <button id="button">SUBMIT</button>

 </section>
 <!--END search section-->
 <!--Section to display gifs for searched word-->
 <section id="layout">
            <div id="result">
            </div>
 </section>
 <!--END display section-->

    </body>
</html>
```

Enjoy !

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but still not working. I was looking with dev tool of chrome and I saw on network tab that I have a json. In my opinion from there is more easy to take data of this api link. I saw that you had tried this, but again, still not working.

Comment: It works on firefox, not on chromium indeed. I'll investigate why.

Comment: I fixed the issue, the code now works properly. (I made a stupid error related to images generation). I updated my answer.